# Poster title in header box

Tags: a0poster

I am making a scientific poster using the a0poster package. I wanted to know if there was any way to make say the top inch of the page a solid colour, and have the title on top of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could serve as a possible solution to the OP's objective. This solution defines two macros via tikz skills for use of the `a0poster package`; one is `postertitle` which is the what the OP needs hopefully :-) and the other is `psection` that are meant for subtitles in the column-wise locations.

**Update:**

Two methods are proposed. Node style (method 1) and macro approach (method 2)

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[final]{a0poster}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

% method 1

\tikzset{mybox/.style = {draw=purple,fill=cyan, line width=0.2cm,rectangle, 
rounded corners, minimum width=\textwidth} 
}

% method 2

\newcommand{\postertitle}[2]  % Poster title
{
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [purple,line width=0.2cm,rounded corners=0.2cm,fill=cyan] (-0.5\textwidth,-4)--
(-0.5\textwidth,4)--(0.5\textwidth,4)--(0.5\textwidth,-4)--cycle;
\draw (0,1)node[anchor=center,rotate=0]{\bfseries \sffamily \fontsize{43}   
{0}\selectfont {}{#1}};
\draw (0,-2)node[anchor=center,rotate=0]{\bfseries \sffamily \fontsize{33}
{0}\selectfont {}{#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.015\textheight}
}

\newcommand{\psection}[1]  % poster section title
{
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [blue,line width=0.2cm, rounded corners=0.2cm] (-7,-1)--(-7,1)--(7,1)--(7,-1)--cycle;
\draw (0,0)node[anchor=center,rotate=0]{\bfseries \sffamily \fontsize{43}{0}\selectfont {}{#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.001\textheight}
}
\begin{document}

\postertitle{The Poster Title}{A. Author1 \& B. Author2}

\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}  % begin of left column

\psection{Left Column 1}
\lipsum[1]
\psection{Left Column 2}

\psection{Left column 3}

\end{minipage}                   % end of left column
\hfill 
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}  % begin of center column

\psection{Center Column 1}

\psection{Center Column 2}
\lipsum[1]

\psection{Center Column 3}
\end{minipage}                   % end of right column
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}  % begin of right column

\psection{Right Column 1}

\psection{Right Column 2}
\psection{Right Column 3}
\lipsum[1]

\end{minipage}                   % end of right column
\end{document}
```