# How to wrap the title in an a0poster with a page width color box?

Tags: pdftex, titles, boxes, tcolorbox, a0poster

### Current Preamble

I want to wrap the top part of my document with a colored banner, spanning the entire page width and to the very top of the document. Here is my preamble and title section:

```
documentclass[a0, landscape]{a0poster}

\usepackage{multicol}           % This is so we can have multiple columns of text side-by-side
\columnsep=100pt                % This is the amount of white space between the columns in the poster
\columnseprule=0pt              % This is the thickness of the black line between the columns in the poster

\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{verbatim}       
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{path}}   % Location of the graphics files
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   POSTER HEADER 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% The header is divided into three boxes:
% The first is 55% wide and houses the title, subtitle, names and university/organization
% The second is 25% wide and houses contact information
% The third is 19% wide and houses a logo for your university/organization or a photo of you
% The widths of these boxes can be easily edited to accommodate your content as you see fit 

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\linewidth}
\veryHuge \color{BrickRed} \textbf{Title of Poster} \color{Black}\\ % Title
\huge \textbf{Authors}\\ % Author(s)
\huge University\\ % University/organization
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
\color{DarkSlateGray}\Large \textbf{Contact Information:}\\
University \\
Address\\\\
Phone: (800)-999-9999\\
Email: email@domain.com\\
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.19\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[width=20cm]{"/Users/hgducharme/Documents/School/Projects/Calculus II Honors/Poster Board/figures/logo"} 
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1cm} % A bit of extra whitespace between the header and poster content

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

### First attempt at solution:

I have tried to use method #2 from [this answer regarding the same problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224202). With all else being same, my code changes to the below block and the result is the image below.

```
%%% Packages %%%

\newcommand{\postertitle}[2]  % Poster title
{
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [purple,line width=0.2cm,rounded corners=0.2cm,fill=cyan] (-0.5\textwidth,-4)--
(-0.5\textwidth,4)--(0.5\textwidth,4)--(0.5\textwidth,-4)--cycle;
\draw (0,1)node[anchor=center,rotate=0]{\bfseries \sffamily \fontsize{43}   
{0}\selectfont {}{#1}};
\draw (0,-2)node[anchor=center,rotate=0]{\bfseries \sffamily \fontsize{33}
{0}\selectfont {}{#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.015\textheight}
}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   POSTER HEADER 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\postertitle{
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\linewidth}
   Title section
\end{minipage}
}
```

[image].

---

### Second Attempt At Solution

I also tried to wrap the section in a color box but that did not work either.

```
\colorbox{Grey!70}{\parbox{\linewidth - 2\fboxsep}{%
%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\linewidth}
   Title Section
\end{minipage}
}}
```

[image].

In the second picture, I like where the bottom of the color box ends. However, I would just like for it to expand the page length, and for the top of the color box to extend up to the top of the page. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you in advance to anyone who is willing to help.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure that I understand ; You want to remove the margin of the document ?

Comment: Not quite. I want to have a header to my a0poster like the one in [this image](http://www.researchposters.com/images/Genigraphics-PowerPoint-Poster-Template.png)

Answer (score 1):

By using tikzpicture (remove showframe to see the header like you want ) :

```
\documentclass[a0, landscape]{a0poster}

\usepackage[margin={1cm,1cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{multicol}           % This is so we can have multiple columns of text side-by-side
\columnsep=100pt                % This is the amount of white space between the columns in the poster
\columnseprule=0pt              % This is the thickness of the black line between the columns in the poster

\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{verbatim}       
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{path}}   % Location of the graphics files
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   POSTER HEADER 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% The header is divided into three boxes:
% The first is 55% wide and houses the title, subtitle, names and university/organization
% The second is 25% wide and houses contact information
% The third is 19% wide and houses a logo for your university/organization or a photo of you
% The widths of these boxes can be easily edited to accommodate your content as you see fit 

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=north west, xshift=1cm, yshift=-1cm] at (current page.north west)
  {
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\linewidth}
        \veryHuge \color{BrickRed} \textbf{Title of Poster} \color{Black}\\ % Title
        \huge \textbf{Authors}\\ % Author(s)
        \huge University\\ % University/organization
      \end{minipage}
      % 
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
        \color{DarkSlateGray}\Large \textbf{Contact Information:}\\
        University \\
        Address\\\\
        Phone: (800)-999-9999\\
        Email: email@domain.com\\
      \end{minipage}
      % 
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.19\linewidth}
        \begin{flushright}
          % \includegraphics[width=20cm]{"/Users/hgducharme/Documents/School/Projects/Calculus II Honors/Poster Board/figures/logo"} 
          \includegraphics[width=20cm]{example-image}
        \end{flushright}
      \end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{1cm} % A bit of extra whitespace between the header and poster content



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what i'm getting: [picture](http://imgur.com/Z8LarlH)

Comment: Please, put the code